# UIStoryboard's instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier SIGABRT crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

## Problem

After checking and double checking the usual solutions, `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` is crashing for a reason beyond my realm of experience.

## Details

I'm trying to use a storyboard view controller for paging with a `UIPageViewController`, with the pagecontroller being a child controller of a root controller, similar to how Apple sets up a page-based project.

I have my storyboard ViewController all labelled up:

[image]

And I'm initializing it as so for paging use:

```
-(MemoImageViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (index >= [pageMemories count] || [pageMemories count] ==0) return nil;
    MemoImageViewController * viewController = [_mainBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MemoImageViewController"];
    viewController.memory = [pageMemories objectAtIndex:index];
   return viewController;
}
```

_mainboard = an UIStoryboard reference of the main and ONLY storyboard I use.

Yet, the app crashes with a SIGABRT with zero explanation as to why.  When I turn on exception breakpoints it leads me to the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method.

## What I've tried

1. I have tried launching a different viewcontroller from the storyboard, and IT WORKED.  Leading me to believe it is something to do with the viewcontroller I'm using itself.
2. Changing the identity, title, storyboard ID up didn't have any effect.
3. I deleted derived data, snapshot, cleaned my project, built several different ways, no use.

I hope this is enough information to evaluate my problem, its very well possible I will just switched the view controller to a xib but I'd like to see if this won't work first.

Thank you, Happy holidays.

Comment: Is MemoImageViewController a UIViewController subclass? Have you logged _mainBoard to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: Yes, its a subclass and _mainboard is not nil.  I used it to instantiate another viewcontroller even

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code -- I wonder if the debugger is pointing to the right place. Try logging viewController on the line right after you instantiate it, and see if that log runs. One other question -- do you have a custom init method in your MemoImageViewController class?

Comment: There is no custom init method, and it doesn't make it past the intstatiation. Just checked to confirm. My thoughts are that they're may be a possibility, for whatever reason, the project hasn't updated to a point where it recognizes the identifier (its a relatively new VC).  Does this sound possible?

Comment: No, I don't think so -- when you build and run, it should update everything. It may have something to do with the particular view controller, as you speculated. I can't imagine what though, if it doesn't have a custom init method, then I would think it would at least get past the instantiating stage.

Comment: Well I solved the problem simply by changing it to a initWithNibName:bundle: though I'm not sure that I can really say I answered my own question.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change from _mainboard to self.storyboard

```
MemoImageViewController * viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MemoImageViewController"];
```

Comment: same issue with self.storyboard